# fork Cocoa process and re-init Cocoa. how?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mach-o

I tried to `fork()` a Cocoa process and setup a new Cocoa/ObjC environment but I get the error:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

Is there a way to re-initialize Cocoa/ObjC in the forked process?

---

I know that the documentation about `fork()` does say it is limited, however I wonder if there is still a way to do it, not just what the documentation says.

I tried to read the [source code of the XNU kernel which handles the execve syscall (bsd/kern/kern_exec.c)](http://codesearch.google.com/#pFm0LxzAWvs/darwinsource/tarballs/apsl/xnu-792.1.5.tar.gz%7CyITfKluHz0o/xnu-792.1.5/bsd/kern/kern_exec.c&q=execve%20darwin&type=cs) but I am not that used to the code that I cannot easily say wether it is possible or not to do something similar in userspace or not.

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X severely limits what you can do after a fork without `exec`ing. See the CAVEATS section of the [fork man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fork.2.html). The allowed actions do not include using Cocoa or CoreFoundation, so you must call `exec` to start a new program.

Comment: I know what the documentation is saying but it doesn't really answer my question wether there might still be a way somehow to do that. I extended my question a bit to show what I have in mind as a possible way.

Comment: @Albert Related: as you can only rely on async-safe functions after you `fork()` and before you `exec()`, take a look at [Landon’s answer to a PLCrashReporter question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312905/using-plcrashreporter-can-you-receive-events-before-the-crash/7365872#7365872).